# Explode jquery появление блока - реализация

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Каким способом реализовать что бы после hover блок b2 возвращался назад ?

```js
$(document).hover(function() {
  $(".b2").hide("explode");
});
```

```css
.b1,
.b2,
img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.b1 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.b2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(200, 220, 230, .5);
}
.b1:hover .b2 {
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b1">
  <img src="http://www.worthytoshare.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/8876509-lily-pretty-girl.jpg" />
  <div class="b2"></div>
</div>
```

здесь не могу в песочнице верно запустить код на jsfiddle работает https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/rvL7nkwh/1/
Как после срабатывания explode вернуть полупрозрачный блок на место ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция hover принимает два аргумента, когда над объектом и второй, когда нет.

```
$( document ).hover(function() {
  $( ".b2" ).hide( "explode" );
}, function() {
  $( ".b2" ).show( "explode" );
});
```

[тут я вам обновил код](https://jsfiddle.net/rvL7nkwh/2/)

Comment: как всегда - ответ очевиден - аж досадно

Comment: это да, часто так бывает :)